# XSLT move node from searched position to another

Tags: xslt

I've found many samples for moving nodes around a parent node, or to group them but none to take a node from a position to be searched and place it in another node which position is to be searched.

Assume we have this structure:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
    <Fragment>
        <DirectoryRef Id="INSTALLFOLDER">
            <Directory Id="dir9AF366290476C56B26201053637AFAA1" Name="Lib">
                <Directory Id="dirC1CF73EF7FB9713B4C9AE6AD5F0D6138" Name="site-packages">
                    <Directory Id="dir4B1B5674B365D05CEA0E3010DE56E3A7" Name="win32">
                        <Component Id="cmp2A1A74B990EA8E9CE27135F83D2DD8EB" Guid="*" Win64="yes">
                            <File KeyPath="yes" Source="$(var.HarvestPath)\Lib\site-packages\win32\pythonservice.exe" Id="fileID_PythonService" />
                        </Component>
                    </Directory>
                </Directory>                
            </Directory>
            <Directory Id="dir33A2F09B010813323099475AA1D7838F" Name="Scripts">
                <Directory Id="dir50CF289B7CF01C2C43A5CDF168EA1A4E" Name="__pycache__" />
            </Directory>
        </DirectoryRef>
    </Fragment>
    <Fragment>
        <ComponentGroup Id="cgroupPythonEnvService">
            <ComponentRef Id="cmp2A1A74B990EA8E9CE27135F83D2DD8EB" />
        </ComponentGroup>
    </Fragment>
</Wix>
```

while the real structure is not known in advance (except the folder name and the file name), I need to get this output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
    <Fragment>
        <DirectoryRef Id="INSTALLFOLDER">
            <Directory Id="dir9AF366290476C56B26201053637AFAA1" Name="Lib">
                <Directory Id="dirC1CF73EF7FB9713B4C9AE6AD5F0D6138" Name="site-packages">
                    <Directory Id="dir4B1B5674B365D05CEA0E3010DE56E3A7" Name="win32">                        
                    </Directory>
                </Directory>                
            </Directory>
            <Directory Id="dir33A2F09B010813323099475AA1D7838F" Name="Scripts">
                <Directory Id="dir50CF289B7CF01C2C43A5CDF168EA1A4E" Name="__pycache__" />
                <Component Id="cmp2A1A74B990EA8E9CE27135F83D2DD8EB" Guid="*" Win64="yes">
                    <File KeyPath="yes" Source="$(var.HarvestPath)\Lib\site-packages\win32\pythonservice.exe" Id="fileID_PythonService" />
                </Component>
            </Directory>
        </DirectoryRef>
    </Fragment>
    <Fragment>
        <ComponentGroup Id="cgroupPythonEnvService">
            <ComponentRef Id="cmp2A1A74B990EA8E9CE27135F83D2DD8EB" />
        </ComponentGroup>
    </Fragment>
</Wix>
```

**Edit #1**

The XSLT part (one of the many tries):

```
  <xsl:key name="id_search_pyservice"   match="wix:Component[contains(wix:File/@Source, 'pythonservice.exe')]"  use="ancestor::wix:Component/@Id " />
  <xsl:key name="id_search_targetdir"   match="wix:Directory[contains(@Name, 'Scripts')]"                       use="@Id" />

  <xsl:template match="wix:Directory[key('id_search_targetdir', @Id)]">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:copy-of select="*" />
      <xsl:apply-templates select="wix:Component[key('id_search_pyservice', @Id)]" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
```

Comment: What language are you working in? What have you tried?

Comment: It is an xslt transform for Wix v3. Tried searching for both keys, which works prety well. But I had no chances trying to copy/replace the template of the target node. Probably because the node to insert is not a subnode of the target node...

`<xsl:key name="id_search_pyservice"   match="wix:Component[contains(wix:File/@Source, 'pythonservice.exe')]" use="@Id" />`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change your `id_search_pyservice` key to:

```
<xsl:key name="id_search_pyservice"
    match="wix:Component[contains(wix:File/@Source, 'pythonservice.exe')]"
    use="@Id " />
```

then, change your template match as:

```
<xsl:template match="wix:Directory[key('id_search_targetdir', @Id)]">
    <xsl:copy>
        <!-- copy also the attributes -->
        <xsl:copy-of select="@*" />
        <xsl:copy-of select="*" />
        <xsl:copy-of select="//wix:Component[key('id_search_pyservice', @Id)]" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

then, create an empty match for the target node to be moved:

```
<xsl:template match="wix:Component[contains(wix:File/@Source, 'pythonservice.exe')]"/>
```

See it in action (http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bFukv8q).

Comment: Wow, spent hours trying around but missed these two slashes in front of the component!!! Thank's a lot for this :o)

However I stubled over another issue now. In the full XLST I add an attribute to the Component nodes (Win64="yes"). When I apply the patch, y do get the component moved as expected but all components under the target node (Directory) loose the "Win64="yes" attribute...
 See this code:
http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bFukv8q/3

To avoid this I found a way using passes but that sound a bit misplaced to do the job: http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bFukv8q/1

Comment: that is because `xsl:copy-of` copied the whole original nodes. You can use a different mode in applying templates to achieve what you want.

Comment: Please see this one (http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bFukv8q/4).

Comment: Thank you! That did the trick (http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bFukv8q/5). Mainly replaced "node()" by " * " and grouped node and attributes to "@*|*", Works fine, alltough i'm not sure if there is a difference for using node or *.